# Can I keep "Always use this app" box unchecked always while clicking any link?

Tags: windows-10, browser

I wanted to do this because, I use multiple browsers. According to my needs, I would like Windows to ask every time which browser to use when I click a link outside a browser (from other softwares like MS Office, SumatraPDF Reader, Discord etc.)
[here's a photo as a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYCzX.png)

But the popup always has a checkbox and by-default it's checked. So every time I have to uncheck it. That's frustrating for me. This kind of box is shown when I click on a link from other app like Discord. My installed browsers are: Chrome, Cent Browser, Firefox. My Win10Pro build is 2004 and another Win10Pro machine is 1809 LTSC.

Is there any way to keep that box unchecked always? I've found a program called "[BrowserPicker](https://github.com/mortenn/BrowserPicker)", which gives the option to choose any installed browser when I click on a URL link outside a browser. But it loads a little slow for the first time I click on a link. So, I am looking for something native or lightweight.

Comment: Where is found this click? Inside a page displayed by a browser?

Comment: Had to test a few different links until I found one that shows this... in my Win10Pro (build 19043) it's unchecked - I always disable it with the first download if it's enabled. So what exactly is your Win version? Have you accidentally at some point perhaps chosen to enable it? Also what is/are the browser(s) that keep it enabled? One way around the issue you can try is to right-click the link and choose `Save as`. Unfortunately this only works with direct download links, not ones that open a download page.

Comment: Please don't answer in a comment. Instead edit your question to add the new info. This way it's readily available for everyone without the need to dig it up from comments.

Comment: @harrymc, found when clicked on any link from apps like Discord, Microsoft Office etc.

Comment: I don't get any popup from Word, for example. It just goes straight to the default browser.

Comment: That's because you already have a browser set as default. This popup is shown when no browser is set as default. Some people, like me wants to use different browsers for different needs and don't want a specific browser to always open links. This always checked checkbox is a pain for our workflow. I found an alternative way, an open-source program called "BrowserPicker". Still, it's not an official solution.